# Extract values between 3 underscores

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to extract part of a character string by underscores, including an underscore:

```
20220801_NM7_Chrom_2399_A12_CCIH.CSV
```

I want get output is

```
Chrom_2399
```

My code is here

```
x = "20220801_NM7_Chrom_2399_A12_CCIH.CSV"
gsub("^(?:[^_]+_){2}([^_]+).*", "\\1", x)
```

It gave me

```
[1] "Chrom"
```

How do I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
^(([^_]+)_(?2))_((?1)).*
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/s2mFN9/1)

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(` - Open the 1st capture group (subpattern);

  - `([^_]+)` - A 2nd nested capture group to match 1+ characters other than underscore;
  - `_(?2)` - Match an underscore and a backreference to the 2nd subpattern to match again 1+ characters other than underscore;
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group/subpattern;
- `_((?1))` - Match an underscore, open a 3rd capture group that matches the entire subpattern used in the 1st group;
- `.*` - Match 0+ characters other than newline.

We can now use the 3rd capture group in our replacement value:

```
s  = "20220801_NM7_Chrom_2399_A12_CCIH.CSV"
gsub("^(([^_]+)_(?2))_((?1)).*", "\\3", s, perl = T)
```

Prints:

```
[1] "Chrom_2399"
```

---

Alternatively use:

```
library(strex)

s  = "20220801_NM7_Chrom_2399_A12_CCIH.CSV"
str_before_nth(str_after_nth(s, "_", 2), "_", 2)
```

Comment: Hi, Could I ask more detail about  ``` gsub("^(([^_]+)_(?2))_((?1)).*", "\\3", s, perl = T) ``` , I can't catch each metacharacter mean.

Comment: @Ollie, sorry I'm afraid I don't understand what you asking me.

Comment: I want to know like [^_]+ can catch which part ,  or and (?2)) can catch which part , I went to  https://regex101.com/  still can't understand. thank you.

Comment: @Ollie, `[^_]+` matches any 1+ characters other than underscore. This is captured in a group which we use in a backreference. So `(?2)` matches the same pattern we used in the 1st group etc.

Comment: After [^_]+ will get 3 grup, 20220801_NM7 and 20220801 and Chrom_2399, then using (?2) to matches the same pattern in 1st . Have I got that right ? thank you .

Comment: Hm, not quite. The regex engine will match left to right starting with `^` as the start-line anchor. It then matches 1+ characters other than underscore, an actual underscore, the same pattern as the 1st group, another underscore and finally match the same pattern as described before and used in the 1st capture group @Ollie.

Comment: One more question , the final ((?1)) is the same like (?2) ? It seems like I need to spend more time to understand ... Thank you . @JvdV

Comment: @Ollie, no it is not the same. I'll edit the question to clarify the pattern better.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! May all your wishes come true!

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```r
x <- "20220801_NM7_Chrom_2399_A12_CCIH.CSV"
sub("^([^_]+_){2}([^_]+_[^_]+)_.*", "\\2", x)
#> [1] "Chrom_2399"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code using the stringr package.

```
library(stringr)

x <- "20220801_NM7_Chrom_2399_A12_CCIH.CSV"
paste0(str_split(x, pattern = "_")[[1]][3],"_",str_split(x, pattern = "_")[[1]][4])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- "20220801_NM7_Chrom_2399_A12_CCIH.CSV"

> stringr::str_extract_all(x, pattern = "[:alpha:]+_[:digit:]+")
[[1]]
[1] "Chrom_2399"
```

Comment: Correct merely by coincidence in this case I think.